# Is there a way to catch a failure in piped commands?

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, pipe

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e    # abort if error
...
command1 2>&1 | command2
...
```

And I notice that sometimes `command1` fails but command2 does not and the shell script happily continues...
if I did not have to use the pipe here, the `set -e` would have been sufficient but now it does not work with the pipe there...

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: that solution delays the processing of the second command line until the first one has finished and uses temp files and their overhead.
not ideal in my situation. I want the piped commands do their work and only fail when one of them happens to return an error... Using temp files would be more of an issue when the output of previous commnds could grow very huge in size...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using bash, other than `set -e` you can also add `set -o pipefail` to get the results you want...