# Shell: analyse return

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to get the result of this call

```
TMP=$(find /mydir/ -type f -mmin +1440 | xargs rm -f)
M=$?
```

Unfortunately, if `/mydir/` doesn't exist, the result of `$?` is still '`0`', like there was not problem. I'd like to get something *not* '`0`' if `find` returns nothing.

How should I do?

Comment: the `-f` on your `rm` cmd is probably overriding any reporting on "error-ish" conditions. Good luck.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923387/is-there-a-way-to-catch-a-failure-in-piped-commands which itself is dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550933/catching-error-codes-in-a-shell-pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

due to  [link](http://bclary.com/blog/2006/07/20/pipefail-testing-pipeline-exit-codes/):

> bash version 3 introduced an option which changes the exit code behavior of pipelines and reports the exit code of the pipeline as the exit code of the last program to return a non-zero exit code. So long as none of the programs following the test program report a non-zero exit code, the pipeline will report its exit code to be that of the test program. To enable this option, simply execute:

```
set -o pipefail
```

Then

```
TMP=$(find /mydir/ -type f -mmin +1440 | xargs rm -f)
M=$?
```

will behave differently and recognize the error.
See also a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550933/catching-error-codes-in-a-shell-pipe) on StackOverflow

Best,

Jack.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable `bash`'s `pipefail` option. Documentation (from `help set`):

```
 pipefail     the return value of a pipeline is the status of
              the last command to exit with a non-zero status,
              or zero if no command exited with a non-zero status
```

So, you could write as:

```
set -o pipefail
TMP=$(find /mydir/ -type f -mmin +1440 | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm -f)
M=$?
set +o pipefail
```

Also, why are you executing your `find` command inside `$( ... )`? If you don't want it to output errors, redirect STDERR to `/dev/null`, and also it is good practice to use the `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty` flag to `xargs`, to avoid running the command if it does not receive any input from the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Check if a directory exists in bash:

```
if [ ! -d "mydir" ]; then
    exit 1 #or whatever you want, control will stop here
fi
TMP=$(find /mydir/ -type f -mmin +1440 | xargs rm -f)
...
```